# An easy way to display prototype nodes in PHP?

Tags: php, html

It's a kind of UI second flavor,

```
function UISecond($elements)
{

}
```

So that this functions shows the specified elements(with name,id and type) which is neccesary,but not too picky about how exactly it's displayed.

**EDIT**

Give it an array,output the HTML.

Anyone has tried this?

**EDIT AGAIN**

I want to develop a render engine like drupal's,which takes the array as parameter,and outputs the HTML automatically.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean print_r()?

Comment: No,the output should be valid html.

Comment: I still don't understand a word, but how about "<pre>".print_r($var, true)."</pre>"; ?

Comment: What are prototype nodes, what is "UI second flavor" what is `$elements`, and generally what are you talking about?

Comment: I need a function that can output a prototype view of html elements, that make sense?

Comment: prototype view of html elements? Can you give an example of input and output?

Comment: @Shadi Almosri ,drupal has done something like this.

Comment: @Mask: if you edit your question with exact input and exact output you would like you'll probably receive better answers. I work and develop with drupal every day, so clarify your question and i might be able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [Krumo](http://krumo.kaloyan.info/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something like this?

```
function UISecond($elements)
{
    foreach($elements as $_elem)
    {
        echo "<{$_elem['type']}";
        foreach($_elem['attribute'] as $_name => $_contents) {
            echo " {$_name}=\"{$_contents}\"";
        }
        echo ">{$_elem['innerHTML']}</{$_elem['type']}>";
    }
}
```

Either way, half of getting a good answer is writing a good problem description ;-)